# Get JSON from Web in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i started with flutter yesterday and try to get json data from web in a listview (I am a beginner).

I create a class for my json data:

```
class Events {
  final int id;
  final int categorie_id;
  final String categorie;
  final DateTime begin;
  final DateTime end;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String ort;
  final String fileurl;
  final int canceled;

  Events({this.categorie_id, this.categorie, this.begin, this.end, this.description, this.ort, this.fileurl, this.canceled, this.id, this.title});

  factory Events.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Events(
      id: json['id'],
      categorie_id: json['categorie_id'],
      categorie: json['categorie'],
      begin: json['begin'],
      end: json['end'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      ort: json['ort'],
      fileurl: json['fileurl'],
      canceled: json['canceled'],
    );
  }
}
```

And that's my code to handle the json:

```
  Future<Events> fetchEvents() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://my.url.de/');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Events.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); // <-- ERROR ROW
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load events from web');
    }
  }
```

and my json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "363",
        "categorie_id": "2",
        "categorie": "Cat 1",
        "begin": "2020-12-20 18:30:00",
        "end": null,
        "title": "title 1",
        "description": "",
        "ort": "",
        "fileurl": "",
        "canceled": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "364",
        "categorie_id": "5",
        "categorie": "Cat 3",
        "begin": "2020-12-28 09:00:00",
        "end": null,
        "title": "title 2",
        "description": "",
        "ort": "",
        "fileurl": "",
        "canceled": "0"
    }
]
```

actual i get an error:

```
E/flutter ( 4461): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'
E/flutter ( 4461): #0      _EventdetailsState.fetchEvents (package:apptest/main.dart:40:11)
E/flutter ( 4461): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I'm looking for help and explanation or a good docu for beginer

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try out **`below code:-`**

```html
Future<Events> fetchEvents() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://my.url.de/');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Events.fromJson(response.body); 
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load events from web');
    }
  }
```

Comment: fromJson expect an Map<String, dynamic>

Answer (score 0):

The json received from your backend is an array of map `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.
To properly map this, you can try

```
List<Events> events = [];
for (var map in jsonDecode(response.body)) events.add(Events.fromJson(map));
return events;
```

Comment: response.body is a string and not Iterable. And current, the return is Future<Events>

Comment: Please refer to the new edit. I mistakenly omitted the `jsonDecode`

Comment: okay, but now i have a List as return value and not a future

Comment: You can change your method prototype from this `Future<Events> fetchEvents() async` to this `Future<List<Events>> fetchEvents() async`

Answer (score 0):

The response is a list of Events, your class is a single Event, even though the name is plural.

Your jsonDecode(response.body) will return a List<Map<String, dynamic>>;

```
Future<List<Events>> fetchEvents() async { // !!Changed return to List<Events>!!
  final response = await http.get('https://my.url.de/');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List<Events> events = [];
    for (var event in jsonDecode(response.body)) {
     events.add(Events.fromJson(event as Map<String, dynamic>));
    }
    return events;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load events from web');
  }
}
```